# Query Active & Inactive Connections based off Machine and Username

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I'm attempting to make a query that lists a count of Active, Inactive & Total number of connections per machine, per username in an Oracle 10g database.

I have the following Query:

```
SELECT count(1) AS con_count, machine, username 
FROM v$session 
WHERE type <> 'BACKGROUND'
GROUP BY username, machine 
ORDER BY con_count DESC;
```

That will list a count of the # of total connections per machine per username but am having trouble adapting it to do a count of Active, Inactive & Total connections as an all in one query.

So results should be something like:

```
ACTIVE   INACTIVE   TOTAL   MACHINE   USERNAME
```

And I can make the query do one of the first three columns but not all three at once.

Any help would be appreciated, as my SQL is very, very rusty.

Comment: What column and what values define **Active** and **Inactive**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Column `status` of `v$session` view contains information about active and inactive sessions. So you could recode you query as follows:

```
SELECT s.machine
     , s.username 
     , count(decode(s.STATUS, 'ACTIVE', 1))   as active_con
     , count(decode(s.STATUS, 'INACTIVE', 1)) as inactive_con
     , count(*)                               as total_con
FROM v$session s
WHERE type <> 'BACKGROUND'
GROUP BY username, machine 
ORDER BY total_con DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. It helps me a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the column **type** can be used to distinguish your status, you can use a `SUM` expression:

```
 select sum(case when status = 'ACTIVE' then 1 else 0 end) as ACTIVE_COUNT
      , sum(case when status = 'INACTIVE' then 1 else 0 end) as INACTIVE_COUNT
      , count(*) as TOTAL_COUNT
      , username, machine
 from   v$session
 where type <> 'BACKGROUND'
 group by username, machine
 order by username, machine
```

Updated based on Nicholas's response that the column **status** should be used.